# Execute two separate methods simultaneously

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

I'm trying two execute two separate methods at the same time using `Backgroundworker` (or if not possible using another method) to gain performance. The idea is to do heavy calculations in methods.

Is it possible at all?

```
private readonly BackgroundWorker _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
private readonly BackgroundWorker _worker2 = new BackgroundWorker();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    _worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    _worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
    _worker.RunWorkerAsync();

    _worker2.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    _worker2.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    _worker2.DoWork += worker_DoWork2;
    _worker2.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // Do something
}

private void worker_DoWork2(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //  Do something simultaneously with worker_DorWork
}
```

Comment: When it comes to IO, parallelism doesn't help much.

Comment: @L.B Lets say it is not about IO. I had mentioned it as an example method. I edited the question.

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to do. If its IO bound work, this wont help much as you can do it asynchronously without using more threads.

Comment: I'm doing heavy calculations in both of the methods. They are not IO bound.

Comment: Your question states that the idea is to _read two different text files simultaneously_. Are you saying that isn't the case?

Comment: What is the problem? And what is the question?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead ... in conjunction with *to gain performance* too. Seems that has been answered appropriately.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I corrected it.

Comment: That is an entirely different question just with you changing that last sentence.. you should make sure you get that right the first time next time - it saves you receiving downvotes.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Unfortunately, I had no idea that it depends on what our method is going to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. A lot of applications today consume multiple threads to do work in parallel. 
When doing such work, one has to notice the pitfalls too.

For example, if you have a shared resource consumed by both WorkerA and WorkerB, you will have to do synchronization with any synchronization primitive (such as a `Mutex`, `Semaphore`, `ManualResetEvent`, etc) that is fit for your scenario.

Also, note that spinning up new threads doesn't come free, there are overheads to each thread such as a 1MB stack for each one created.

Note, i'd advise you to look into more modern libraries for doing parallel work such as the [`Task Parallel Library`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx) that was introduced in .NET 4.0. Specifically, look into the [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Parallel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel(v=vs.110).aspx) classes.

**Edit**

As per your question in the comments, lets see what it looks like to use a `Task` vs `BackgroundWorker`:

**BackgroundWorker:**

```
_worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
_worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
_worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
_worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

**Task:**

```
var task = Task.Run(worker_DoWork);
```

or if you're on .NET 4.0:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(worker_DoWork);
```

You also get the benefits of [*cancellation*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364(v=vs.110).aspx), [*continuation*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372288(v=vs.110).aspx), and the use of [*async-await*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) with the `Task` unit, which makes it far easier to do parallel programming.

Comment: Thanks, using BackgroundWorker is a bad idea? Using the above code I'm missing parts of the calculations in the methods.

Comment: It is not a bad idea, no. Consuming `Task` is cleaner, and you get the benefits of using the ThreadPool, instead of creating a new thread. Also, you get the benefits of cancellation and continuation out of the box, which makes parallel programming easier.

Comment: Thanks, but what about executing two separate methods using `BackgroundWorker`?

Comment: @Vahid Is there anything specific you would like to know about that? As i said, there is no problem offloading heavy computation bound work with a `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: I don't know how two run the second method. See my implementation in the question.

Comment: What do you mean by *"dont know how to run second method"*? `_worker2.RunWorkerAsync();` will execute your second backgroundworker.

Comment: Does it execute it after the first one. It seems so from the look of it.

Comment: It executes it at that exact line, disregarding any previous operation you did. Meaning, it doesn't take the previous `BackgroundWorker` into consideration, it doesn't even know of its existence. Its an isolated unit of work which will be ran independently.

Comment: By the way, why the .Net 4 doesn't recognize `var task = Task.Run(worker_DoWork);`?

Comment: For .NET 4.0, use `Task.Factory.StartNew`

Comment: Just one more question. How can I know that the calculations in both methods are finished? I want to execute one final method after these are finished. Can you please give me a BackgroundWorker-specific solution?

Comment: Sure, you can register to [`BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

Comment: How can I know that both of the have completed. If I assign it like `_worker1.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;` what about the second one? Obviously one of them will finish earlier and the `worker_RunWorkerCompleted` will be executed. I want it to be executed after both of them have finished.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned before, doing IO simultaneous will not gain you much profit.

If it is the calculating that is heavy, yes, you could use a `BackgroundWorker`, or even better a [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx) (from the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx)).

```
Task t1 = Task.Run( () => HeavyMethod1() );
Task t2 = Task.Run( () => HeavyMethod2() );

await Task.WaitAll(new Task[] {t1, t2});
```

Comment: That makes two of us ;)

Comment: Thanks Patrick, the Tasks will run in the background using this method? I mean will my UI be responsive?

Comment: ..edit: Perhaps `await` a `Task.WhenAll` instead to maintain responsiveness.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Isn't the namespace `System.Threading.Tasks`? It doesn't recognize Run. Strange.

Comment: It does. Strange. What version of .net are you using?

Answer (score 2):

It depends much on what you want to achieve but yes, it is possible to execute them independent one to another, but this does not necessary mean that you will execute them in the same time. (for example if you have single core cpu it's impossible for 2 threads to be scheduled for execution on the CPU at the same time :) ).

Creating Threads is a huge performance hit (you can easily see that by yourself, try creating threads in a loop and you'll see :) ). A better idea is to create a ThreadPool Task and let .NET decide if more than one thread is needed to execute your operations (You can start here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y(v=vs.110).aspx).

EDIT:

Check @PatrickHofman answer to see code for creating tasks.

Comment: Thanks Dan for the answer/link.

Answer (score 1):

Have you see the new asynchronous methods that Microsoft added into the .NET Framework in .NET 4.5? While they won't actually read two text files at the exact same time, they will definitely improve the performance of your application. You could use the [`TextReader.ReadToEndAsync` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.readtoendasync(v=vs.110).aspx) for example (taken from the [`StreamReader.ReadToEndAsync` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoendasync(v=vs.110).aspx) page):

```
String result;
using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("existingfile.txt"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Opened file.");
    result = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("Contains: " + result);
}
```

For further information regarding these new asynchronous methods, please see the [Asynchronous File I/O](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kztecsys(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: This is now not the correct answer - since the OP has stated "heavy calculations" as the requirement - not reading files simultaneously. You've been beaten by the OP's edit.

Comment: Yes, too bad. Good answer though.

Comment: Thanks Sheridan, I'm sorry for the edit. When asking the question I had no idea about IO, this is still very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TPL to perform parallel calculations. It makes it easy for you to do time consuming work and wait for it to finish. See attached example. You need to use Task.WaitAll() to wait for all tasks to finish, or alternatively, the TPL will wait on all tasks on which you use the .Result property, as in the case below.

```
var startTime = DateTime.Now;

Task<int> longCalculationResult = Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(PerformSomeLongCalculations);
Task<int> longerCalculationResult = Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(PerformSomeEvenLongerCalculations);

//Task.WaitAll(); // Wait for both calculations to finish

// or you can access results of both tasks, which will wait for them to finish in the background

Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", longCalculationResult.Result, longerCalculationResult.Result);

var timeTaken = (DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalSeconds;

Console.WriteLine("It took {0} seconds to calculate the results.", timeTaken);
```

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of concepts will allow you to do this,Since you've stressed on executing two method's at once you can go for **Multi-threading.** **Task parallelism** also helps to achieve your goal.
If you want more specific answer's just Google **"Multi-Threading in .NET"**. Be cautious Threaded apps are difficult to debug and if not handled correctly may lead to strange results.